# How to restore mouth PH balance after lime soda?

Tags: nutrition, dentistry

Squashed lime soda is my favorite drink. And I usually combine it with coffee. I recently learnt the drink creates an very low, acidic pH level in mouth which can cause tooth enamel to decay and expose teeth to plaque. Is there anything I can consume after the drink, which would restore neutral PH balance to my mouth?

Comment: Milk of magnesia or calcium carbonate  containing products (antacid remedies), should do the trick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Water is typically pH neutral at around pH7. Sometimes you can also buy bottled varieties with a more alkaline character so something closer to pH8. Now there's a basic chemical reaction called [neutralization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutralization_(chemistry)). In essence, all you have to do is rinse your mouth with water several times to neutralize the acid.

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote?

Comment: Probably won't happen. Answers here that are less than thorough treatises seem to attract at least one downvote even when they are correct and adequate for the question asked, as I think yours is.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible products that can be used to restore pH. Some work faster, some have some additional properties. See this quote from "[Influence of five neutralizing products on intra-oral pH after rinsing with simulated gastric acid](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21726291)" (DOI: 10.1111/j.1600-0722.2011.00841.x.):

> After rinsing with the two acid solutions (pH 1 and pH 2), the following products were used: (i) antacid tablet; (ii) gum arabic lozenge; (iii) mineral water; (iv) milk; and (v) tap water (positive control). (...) The five test products were used for 2 min after the erosive challenge. All the products produced an initially higher pH compared with the negative control. The antacid tablet resulted in the greatest and most rapid increase in pH, followed by the lozenge. In dental practice, the use of any of the neutralizing products tested, especially the antacid tablet, could be recommended in order to increase the intra-oral pH after an erosive challenge.

Answer (score -1):

I asked my dentist about this and he said that you don't need to add anything to raise your pH because your saliva already produces calcium bicarbonate and it protects us from acid. We just need to consciously apply it with our tongue, or push it around, routinely, or, if you chew gum after you eat, even if it has sugar, it stimulates the saliva to clean and protect your teeth!!